# Using tee and jq to write txt and json log files

Tags: bash, sh, jq, tee

I'd like to write two log files using tee, first log file as txt, second log file as json

Tee is working for two txt files, but can't get jq to work with tee...

My code:

```
logfilename="log_download_2017"
echo "start process $(date -u)" | tee -a $logfilename.txt >> jq . $logfilename.json
echo "logfilename" $logfilename | tee -a $logfilename.txt >> jq . $logfilename.json
```

Console output:

`tee: .: Is a directory
tee: .: Is a directory`

Log files output:

`start process Mon May 15 03:14:09 UTC 2017
logfilename log_download_2017`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like you want:

```
 echo "start process $(date -u)" | tee -a "$logfilename.txt" | jq . >> "$logfilename.json"
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the piping issue and now tee is sending the echoed text to jq. Next step is to work on the jq filters to convert the text into json. Thanks again, new question opened for assistance with initial jq filter options.